# Excel 2010 tracking recurring requirements that expire in months and not days

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I am trying to set up a tracker that tracks recurring requirements based off months and not days.
For example, if something qualifies on 10-15-2016 and the qualification is good for 6 months than they would not lapse until 05-01-2017 or when the cell exceeds 04-2017.  I would like to have the cells turn yellow when the individual is within 2 months of lapsing and red when the individuals exceeds 6 months.
I know how to set this up utilizing days (e.g. 180 days) but that is not completely accurate to what I need.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a Google for the`EOMONTH()` function: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=eomonth+function

Answer (score 0):

Formula 1 `=AND(COUNTA($A2)>0,TODAY()>=EDATE($A2,6))`

Formula 2 `=AND(COUNTA($A2),TODAY()>=EDATE($A2,4))`

```
Edate(date,months) Formula that add months to date
```

CountA for empty cell

Column A is the column of dates that you want to track

- Select the Date
- Conditional Formatting
- New Rule
- Use Formula to determine which cells to format
- Write the above formula 1
- Format as you like
- Ok

Repeat the same with formula 2 and change the formatting